# class not found

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{style} % Use US Letter paper, change to a4paper for A4 
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\ci#i{\textcircled{\resizebox{.5em}{!}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

%--------------------------------------------------
%              Title Selection
%--------------------------------------------------

\namesection{{Istiak}}{Shovon}
{
\href{mailto:Istiakshovon001@gmail.com}{\ci{\faEnvelope}} {\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont \href{mailto:Istiakshovon001@gmail.com}{Istiakshovon001@gmail.com}}
}

{
\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/istiak-shovon-246698206/}{\ci{\faLinkedin}} {\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/istiak-shovon-246698206/}{Istiak Shovon}}
}

{
\href{https://github.com/Istiakshovon}{\ci{\faGithub}} {\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont \href{https://github.com/Istiakshovon}{Istiak}}
}
    
\end{document}
```

Error :

> File `style.cls' not found. \usepackage

The error is representing first line. I tried by changing `style` to `article`. Then, I am getting another error on `fontawesome`. Then, `hyperref`. I am getting error in every single line.

I took the source code from this [git repository](https://github.com/mahshiv/CV/blob/master/Latex/main.tex)

Every error is saying that `class not found. \def`

[image]

Comment: Erh, the missing style.cls is also found on that github.

Comment: @daleif Did she add those class? than, worked? I think you are actually saying that those are explicit classes. I am new to `Latex`. I am not sure what is going on

Comment: First of all style imo is a bad name for a cls file as they are collectively called styles. If you want to use the file you downloaded you probably need all files from that folder. Note however that this might not be a good template as for example hyperref should be loaded as the last package, I think fontawesome is now called fontawesome5. Thus in general be a bit sceptical about random templates you found on the Internet.

Comment: I clone the repo in https://github.com/mahshiv/CV, and I compile with `latexmk -xelatex main`. It works without error(s). So what did you do with the cv template and what distribution do you use? MikTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: @Syvshc I use TeX Studio

Comment: Well, TeXStudio is not a distribution but an editor like vscode, sublime, etc. Did you install something like TeXLive or MiKTeX? Would you please tell us what you did to build the cv template? For example, I downloaded the whole folder, and compiled with `pdflatex` blahblahblah...

Comment: @Syvshc Yes! I installed TeXLive. I just copy and paste those codes and downloaded and put them in my folder.

Answer (score 1):

**This time I'll tell you how to compile this CV. However you'd better learn some basic knowledge of LaTeX with `texdoc lshort` or other books.**

I think you have to download the `.zip` or clone the whole repo in https://github.com/mahshiv/CV
[image: download or clone]

and check that your default compiler is `xelatex` in `Options -> configure TeXStudio -> Build -> Default Compiler`
[image: configure]

and then make sure that `style.cls` is in the same folder as `main.tex`
[image: check the folder]

At last click `Build & View` when your TeXStudio focuses on `main.tex`
[image]

After waiting a moment you can get the `main.pdf` file's view in the right side, and the `main.pdf` file lies in the same folder as `main.tex`.
[image]
[image]

Happy TeXing~

Comment: From that git repo I didn't get any `style.cls`

Comment: The `style.cls` is in CV/Latex

Comment: I am getting just like this `Error: One command expansion invalid.
    Parent Command: compile
    Primary Command: quick` In messages. But, there's no error or message in Log